# Struts2 JQuery : Ajax Submit Form, Server Form Validation and Success Redirection

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, struts2, submit

I have the following layout in my web applications using struts2 framework.

**main_layout.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    jquery is linked here

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
    $.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    });

        $("#newRecord").click(function(){
            $("#content").html("loading...").load("showNewRecordEntry.action");
        });
});
    </script>
</head>  
<body>
<div id='header'>
</div>
<div id='content_wrapper'>
    <div id='navigation'>
        <input type="button" id="newRecord" value="New Record" />
    </div>
    <div id='content'>
       --- ajax is called to put contents
    </div>
</div>
<div id='footer'>
</div>`
</body></html>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="showNewRecordEntry" method="showNewRecordEntry"  class="recordAction">
<result name="success">/WEB-INF/web/new_record.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="saveRecord" method="saveRecord"  class="recordAction">
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">showRecordList</param>
</result>

<result name="input" type="redirectAction">
   <param name="actionName">showNewRecordEntry</param>
</result>

<result name="error" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">showNewRecordEntry</param>
</result>
</action>

<action name="showRecordList" method="showRecord"  class="recordAction">
<result name="success">/WEB-INF/web/record_list.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**new_record.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>

<s:form action="saveRecord">
<s:textfield  name="name" />
<s:textfield   name="address" />
<s:submit />
</s:form>
```

I manually added jquery-1.8.js inside the `<head>` tag of this page to do the Ajax Call.
When a menu is clicked from navigation `<div>` I am calling a struts2 action using `$.ajax` and load the result inside content `<div>`.  This includes data entry form in my application.

I wanted to `submit` the data to a struts2 action and on success I want to call another struts2 action (List of Records) without refreshing the whole page replacing only the content `<div>`.  And in the event of Server validation error, using Ajax, the validation error message must be displayed on top of field that has error. (Without reloading the page)

I want to do this without using struts2-jquery plugin since i already added manually the jquery1.8.js in my main page.

Submit is working fine, it submits the form to my struts2 action but upon success, the sucess action reloads the whole page.

I hope that you guys could help me find a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what is the problem you are getting? and i am not sure about calling second action since you seems not doing anything is first action or you want to pull some data and show it or based on the data from first action want to call second action etc?

Comment: there is no errors, but when I submit my form and returns succesfully,  the success action doesnt go to the 'content' div. it replaces all the content of my page.  I want the success action result to go to <div 'content'>

Comment: You have to prevent the default behaviour of the forms when you want to do an AJAX call.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? How to do it and what should be configured let's say I have a form inside a <div 'content'></div>

Comment: Put a complete example with the form then in the question =)

Comment: I updated the post with form code and struts action config.  thanks dude.  saving is no problems. But i want it to be ajax so that only 'content' div will  be reloaded and not the whole page

Comment: So add javascript code to submit the form and update the div.

Comment: yeah. I ended up writing a jquery plugin that submits the form and a callback that updates the div when the action returns success or when theres a validation error. Still using Server side struts validation.

Answer (score 0):

see the example below I have used to upload image without submitting the whole page  and displaying that.

```
<html>
<script>
 function addMatsImage(){       

    $("#matImageFormDialog").dialog("open");

    var asyncFormFrame=document.getElementById("acsyncFormSubmitterFrame");
    asyncFormFrame.removeAttribute("onload");
    var brwsRequestId = Math.random();
    asyncFormFrame.onload = function() {
        $("#matImgDisp").empty();
        var imgURL1='<s:url action="async.streamImage?brwsRequestId='+brwsRequestId+'&token=_matImageUploaded&imgType=jpeg" namespace="/misc" />'
        var img1 = $("<img width='200' height='200' />").attr('src', imgURL1)
        .load(function() {
            if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {

            } else {
                $("#matImgDisp").append(img1);
            }
        });

    };

}
</script>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
            <td width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <a id="matImgDisp" class="zoomImage" title="" style="cursor: url('<%= request.getContextPath()%>/images/zoomin.cur');" href="<s:url action="async.streamImage?token=_matImageUploaded&imgType=jpeg" namespace="/misc" />">
                    <img width="200" height="200" alt="" src="<s:url action="async.streamImage?token=_matImageUploaded&imgType=jpeg" namespace="/misc" />">
                </a>                                                            
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="200" >
                <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="addMatsImage()" Class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text" Style="background-image: url('../layout/images/btnplanning.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat; color: #FFFFFF" />                                                          
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>    
        <sj:dialog id="matImageFormDialog" autoOpen="false" cssStyle="font: inherit;"
            modal="true" width="350" height="150" title="Upload Image"
            buttons="{
                        'Submit':function() { uploadMatImage(); },
                        'Cancel':function() { cancelMatImageUpload(); }
                    }" >
            <s:form id="IDmatImageForm" name="matImageForm" action="async.uploadImage" namespace="/misc" target="acsyncFormSubmitterFrame" enctype="multipart/form-data">                               

            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="left" style="font: inherit;">
                <tr>
                    <td><s:text name="Upload Image" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <s:hidden name="tokenName" id="IDtokenName" value="_matImageUploaded" />
                        <s:file name="imageFileUploaded" id="imageFileUploaded"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>                                               

            </table> 
            </s:form>
        </sj:dialog>                                        
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <iframe id="acsyncFormSubmitterFrame" name="acsyncFormSubmitterFrame" style="display: none;"></iframe>  
    </td>                                   
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```